# How to go from an Activity to a specific Fragment inside a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I've been working on this problem now for several hours but still couldnt figure it out.
I have a MainActivity with several Tabs, which are all linked to their own fragment. The Tabs and their fragments are all working perfectly fine.

**Main Activity with different Tabs(Fragments):**
[image: Main Activity with different Tabs(Fragments)]

When I switch to the second Tab you can see a button.

**MainActivity and Tab2(Fragment1):**
[image: MainActivity and Tab2(Fragment1)]

Through the button "Theorie" you are navigated to the SecondActivity.

**SecondActivity:**
[image: SecondActivity]

Now there is the following problem. I would like to return to Tab2 in the MainActivity. But because this is the second fragment of the MainActivity, I always get transfered  only to the first Tab "Home" in the MainActivity with the following code.

`

```
ImageView homebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homebtn);
 homebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

`

I really don't know, how I can get through the homebtn to the second Fragment "Tab2" instead of the first Fragment "Home" in the MainActivity. When I conducted a research about this problem, I only found solutions how to transfer data from on fragment to another or how to get from the MainActivity to its fragments. I couldn't find any solutions for my specific problem.

If you have any advice for me how to solve this problem, I would be very thankful :)

Greetings
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are going to the Second activity, don't finish the first activity. And on home button just use this :-

```
finish();
```

Instead of:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are finishing the first activity in the process and starting a new activity altogether which resets everything.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Sarthak Gandhi thank you very much for your answer. It is working now. I just want to ask you, if there is also another method to  get back instead of the Tab2 Fragment to the Tab3 Fragment? Also isn't closing the first activity pretty memory intensive?

Comment: Yes you can use startActivityForResult() pattern to go to tab 3 when you return. And no it is not memory intensive to keep activities in background.